# How to deny everyone access except certain hosts and IPs with Apache 2.4?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

I've read the first results in google and Apache 2.4 docs and there is no clear example.

Currently this works (from 2.2) in a .htaccess file, I can access within the office wifi/LAN but not from my mobile/cell network:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
allow from 123.123 example.com
```

I want the same using 2.4, so I tried:

```
Require ip 123.123
Require host example.com
```

And even:

```
Require ip 123.123
Require host example.com
Require all denied
```

And even changing the order of the lines, with denied at the top.  Still can't get it too work, I can manage to access the page from my mobile/cell network.

What have I missed?

PS - AllowOverride All in the directory conf and the deprecated commands work, but not the new 2.4 stuff.

Comment: Could you please show us your httpd `error_log`? The use of `.htaccess` are granted in `httpd.conf` with the `AllowOverride` directive?